# can RGB-D camera work on micro scale object?

Tags: image-processing, rgb, camera-calibration

Excuse me everyone, I have a question related to RGB-D camera. I want to know whether RGB-D camera can estimate the depth of small object (0.5mm - 5mm depth)

Comment: this question is a) not programming related and b) lacks any information that would allow to answer it. what kind of RGB-D camera? budget? which distance, which measurement time? what kind of object surface/material? there are many imaging systems capable of doing this.

Comment: However, I want to know the depth of aggregate (small rock) from the pavement surface. the distance from the surface is up to 15cm. For the kind of camera and and budget are not concern.

Comment: search the web for pavement scanner, pavement profiler or pavement 3d measurement you'll find plenty of resources and products.